# Character(Avtar) Customization in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I'm trying to create character(Avtar) customization in Flutter based on SVG for the mobile app and flutter web, Can anyone help me with this?
Basically which reference needs to follow to achieve this? Also, help with how to handle responsiveness for this feature. Thanks!!!

I want to update SVG based on position, size, color, etc.

Comment: I would be interested in this too! Am thinking of developing a bunch of modular versions/accessories for a character in a project and it seems like we have a lot of overlap in the core concept

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, what is your use case but, i think you trying to develop something like this [Design](https://dribbble.com/shots/16721874-Les-Embiez-2021-Avatar-builder).

I assume you know how to customize the SVG in flutter then you can use some state management tools like bloc or cubit, where the the main SVG(your avatar) wrapped in it. And you can build other widget that will used to customize it and add some event to change colours, cloths and face details on that you will make changes to the avatar SVG and emit some state that will be lead to showing it in the frontend with blocBuilder or blocListener.